Dark Overlay while navigate table and search in laravel fillament 3.2
i have a problem when navigating in table and searching for items in laravel filament a dark overlay appears but no modal, pop up or anything, and i cant close it, and i need to refresh the page and the dark overlay is gone, but the navigation and searching works but there is a dark overlay which is annoying[this after i search] this after i refresh the page(https://i.sstatic.net/cSyZbpgY.png)
is this because there is css blocking it?

This question really needs some code to identify its problem, there are so many variables that can cause something like this

I have had the same problem, checking the filament repository for the same issue some people said to force livewire to downgrade
Inside composer.json
"livewire/livewire": "3.5.12"
Then use composer to update livewire
composer update livewire/livewire

I think the issue is Livewire State Changes
State updates in Livewire, such as mountedActions or mountedTableActions, are reflected in the modal's visibility due to the Livewire data bindings.When updateing the paginator your updating a propraty called $tableRecordsPerPage in trait CanPaginateRecords. For now this is what i reached.
